# Django Rest Framework permission_class

Tags: python, django, rest, permissions, django-rest-framework

I am new to DRF, and I had came across the following problem when I trying to customize the [Permission](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/) in DRF.

Suppose I had the following code in my permissions.py file:

```
class GetPermission(BasePermission):
    obj_attr  = 'POITS'

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        user = request.user
        employee = Employee.objects.get(user=user)
        # Return a dict which indicates whether the request user has the corresponding permissions
        permissions = get_permission(employee.id)
        return permissions[GetPermission.obj_attr]
```

And in my view, I want to override the static variable in the GetPermission class:

```
class AssignmentList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    GetPermission.obj_attr = 'ASSIGNMENT'
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsStaff, GetPermission)
    queryset = Assignment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AssignmentSerializer
    pagination_class = LargeResultsSetPagination

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        employee = Employee.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        serializer.save(sender=employee, status=0, operatable=0)
```

However, as the documentation of DRF points out:

> Permission checks are always run at the very start of the view, before any other code is allowed to proceed.

So how am I supposed to do, thanks in advance, any ideas will be welcomed, since I am a new fish to DRF.

Comment: I don't understand your question. How is that permission class incompatible with being run at the start of the view?

Comment: For different views, I want to use  GetPermission class with a different obj_attr  value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create subclasses of your permission for each attribute, and use `self.obj_attr` inside the `has_permission` method.

```
class DefaultPermission(GetPermission):
    obj_attr = 'POITS'

class AssignmentPermission(GetPermission):
    obj_attr = 'ASSIGNMENT'
```

Comment: I got a bunch of permission attributes, which means I need many subclass for each attribute? I was wondering if there is a better way.